# What is the price of CiviCRM?

Tags: installation, evaluating-civicrm

Can i know the price for this CRM? I'm planning to get a CRM application for our organization and this look like a perfect match. Appreciate if you can let me know the cost for the full implementation

Comment: Good answers above, I'd second Xavier - try to meet up with other CiviCRM users and providers in your area to make an informed decision!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CiviCRM is open source, so the software itself is free to download. So depending on your skills and availability of hosting it could be free.

In practice, hosting costs (a bit of) money. It will cost your organisation time to learn to use CiviCRM. And if you would want extra help you would pay it to one of the CiviCRM Partners you could hire. (The Partner list can be found here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors.)

If your organisation starts using CiviCRM you could help support the CiviCRM community by a (yearly) donation or by becoming a CiviCRM member (https://civicrm.org/become-a-member).

But all that is voluntary and completely under your own control.

When you like CiviCRM at first sight you can get more hands on experience by looking at http://demo.civicrm.org.

After that you could try to download and install it (https://civicrm.org/become-a-member).

Let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. Quick things to clarify, my country is not listed in your CiviCRM partners. If so how can I get application support or issues reporting

Comment: Well, you can actually choose from other countries, it's a worldwide community. It might come handy if a service provider is able to visit you, but not completely necessary.

Comment: Agreed. Some partners are more focussed on their own country, others provide support around the globe remotely.

Answer (score 8):

- CiviCRM licence: $0
- For the rest: how long is a piece of string?

How much it cost depends a lot of the specifics of your organisation, if you have the time to install and configure, if you need custom development, if you need more training and advices, if you need consultants to help migrating the data from various legacy systems...

In my experience, it is cheaper than closed source systems, and more importantly, it's more sustainable, as you keep more control on your CRM, however, don't expect it to be free unless you have time (or someone in the team/a volunteer) to learn and configure it.

I would recommend you to go to a meetup with other users and providers in your area (there is one coming soon) http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviDay+2016, they might help you gauge better how much help you might need and share their experience

Answer (score 1):

If you are a DIY type you just need a good hosting account not the $4-10 type but more like a $20-40 VPS style account and you can go from there. It is good to have a transactional mail service such as Mandrill which is free if there is not a lot of volume. But it will make huge URL's. Pair it with your favorite CMS Joomla, Drupal, or blogging tool Wordpress.