# The Cost of Civi

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I work for a charity and we are considering Civi as I used it through a previous workplace.

I was wondering what the costs are - is it one off or monthly?

Are you able to give me a rough quote for the following, separately and combined please?:

Hosting our website/ so that we can manage content ourselves
CRM
Donations
Newsletters

I look forward to hearing from you.

With thanks and best wishes,
Janice

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your question and welcome to CiviCRM!

CiviCRM is open source software.  This means that you don't have to pay a license fee to use it.  So in theory you can use it for free.

However, unless you are technically inclined you would probably benefit from having a [partner](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) set up CiviCRM for you.  Most organisations go down this route.

There are also other costs to consider such as hosting.

It is difficult to give an estimate without knowing much more about what you need.  If you get in touch with one of the partners I'm sure they will be able to give you an estimate.

See also this related question: [What is the price of CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/what-is-the-price-of-civicrm/)