# Cost for Booster Club Auction Event

Tags: wordpress, evaluating-civicrm

I am the chair person of organizing a silent/live auction for our Booster Club.  Looking at streamlining processes. Need cost info please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the price of CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/what-is-the-price-of-civicrm)

Comment: Unclear from your question if you are already using civicrm and reaching out here for advice on how to change a setting. if someone set civi up for you perhaps you need to reach out to them initially

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackExchange.  There are several similar questions and answers that you might find useful.

- [The Cost of Civi](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11597/the-cost-of-civi)
- [How much does it cost?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20388/how-much-does-it-cost)
- [Quote for set up and on-going](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20390/quote-for-set-up-and-on-going)
- [What is the price of CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/what-is-the-price-of-civicrm)

Obviously for anyone to provide more specific costs they would need much more information about what you want to do, but auctions are not a core feature of CiviCRM.  You could try contacting someone on this list to discuss further: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors